# How can I refresh the html sourced data in jquery dataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I use html sourced data when I use jquery dataTable, but the content of the table will change(both the content of the cell and the number of rows), so I need to refresh the html sourced data of dataTable, how? I don't want to use ajax, because in that way I have to change my code on server side, and I don't want to add the data line by line(if it is possible),I just want to refresh the html source data when the table change,like the way I initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `draw()` function of datatables.

Ex.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();


    $('#myFilter').on( 'keyup', function () {
        table
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
```

you can check more on below link

https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: It doesn't work, but this works.                                                               var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 $('#submit').on( 'click', function () {
    $.getJSON( 'newTable', null, function ( json ) {
        table.destroy();
        $('#myTable').empty(); // empty in case the columns change
 
        table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            columns: json.columns,
            data:    json.rows
        } );
    } );
} );